# Healthkit per hour Activity summary containing steps, distance and calories?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, hkhealthstore

Querying Healthkit should return an object of array that contains steps, distance and calories.

I was able to return them individually by 
**Activity Steps/hr**

```
func activitySteps(_ startDate:NSDate, endDate:NSDate, anchorDate:NSDate, completion: @escaping (Array<NSObject>, NSError?) -> ()) {
    let type = HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)
    let interval = NSDateComponents()
    interval.hour = 1

    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate as Date, end: endDate as Date, options: .strictEndDate)
    let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: type!, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: [.cumulativeSum], anchorDate: anchorDate as Date, intervalComponents:interval as DateComponents)

    query.initialResultsHandler = { query, results, error in
      if let myResults = results{
        var stepsArray: [NSObject] = []
        myResults.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate as Date, to: endDate as Date) {
          statistics, stop in

          if let quantity = statistics.sumQuantity() {
            let steps = quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())
//            print("\(statistics.endDate.timeIntervalSince1970): steps = \(steps)")

            let ret =  [
              "steps": steps,
              "startDate" : statistics.startDate.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0,
              "endDate": statistics.endDate.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0
              ] as [String : Any]
            stepsArray.append(ret as NSObject)
          }
        }
        completion(stepsArray, error as NSError?)
      }
    }

    healthKitStore.execute(query)
  }
```

**Activity Distance/hr**

```
func activityDistance(_ startDate:NSDate, endDate:NSDate, anchorDate:NSDate, completion: @escaping (Array<NSObject>, NSError?) -> ()) {
    let type = HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.distanceWalkingRunning)
    let interval = NSDateComponents()
    interval.hour = 1

    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate as Date, end: endDate as Date, options: .strictEndDate)
    let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: type!, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: [.cumulativeSum], anchorDate: anchorDate as Date, intervalComponents:interval as DateComponents)

    query.initialResultsHandler = { query, results, error in
      if let myResults = results{
        var distanceArray: [NSObject] = []
        myResults.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate as Date, to: endDate as Date) {
          statistics, stop in

          if let quantity = statistics.sumQuantity() {
            let distance = quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.meter())
            print("\(statistics.endDate.timeIntervalSince1970): distance = \(distance)")

            let ret =  [
              "distance": distance,
              "startDate" : statistics.startDate.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0,
              "endDate": statistics.endDate.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0
              ] as [String : Any]
            distanceArray.append(ret as NSObject)
          }
        }
        completion(distanceArray, error as NSError?)
      }
    }

    healthKitStore.execute(query)
  }
```

**Activity Calories/hr**

```
func activityCalories(_ startDate:NSDate, endDate:NSDate, anchorDate:NSDate, completion: @escaping (Array<NSObject>, NSError?) -> ()) {
    let type = HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.activeEnergyBurned)
    let interval = NSDateComponents()
    interval.hour = 1

    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate as Date, end: endDate as Date, options: .strictEndDate)
    let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: type!, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: [.cumulativeSum], anchorDate: anchorDate as Date, intervalComponents:interval as DateComponents)

    query.initialResultsHandler = { query, results, error in
      if let myResults = results{
        var caloriesArray: [NSObject] = []
        myResults.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate as Date, to: endDate as Date) {
          statistics, stop in

          if let quantity = statistics.sumQuantity() {
            let calories = quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.kilocalorie())
            print("\(statistics.endDate.timeIntervalSince1970): calories = \(calories)")

            let ret =  [
              "calories": calories,
              "startDate" : statistics.startDate.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0,
              "endDate": statistics.endDate.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0
              ] as [String : Any]
            caloriesArray.append(ret as NSObject)
          }
        }
        completion(caloriesArray, error as NSError?)
      }
    }

    healthKitStore.execute(query)
  }
```

I would instead like to combine all these into a single object.

```
 [
    {
         steps: 70,
         distance:10,
         calories: 200,
         startDate: ...,
         endDate: ...,
     },...
 ]
```

Is it possible to generate above format data with an hourly interval rate directly from HealthKit itself?
If it isn't possible how can I combine all 3 data into a single object where data can range from single day- week- month.

Comment: Not sure if you can have a compound query returning multiple sample types, but even if you can't, you can run your queries in parallel. For more information, see [Better way to run multiple HealthKit sample queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29854990/4667835)

Comment: @DávidPásztor yes this was the solution that I have implemented. I am getting all 3 stepsArr, DiatanceArr, CaloriesArr and then combining all these together based on their endDate. But felt there should be a better option than this without increasing both space and time complexity. A magical query that I must be missing.